# mysql count not working correctly?

Tags: mysql

I know PHP's ext/mysql API is outdated and i shouldn't be using it, however this is not my question, my question is i have this piece of code which counts the id's in my table, it was working and now its not, for no reason as far as i can see.

can someone please show me where i am going wrong with the code thanks.

im getting this error:

```
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site.com/includes/functions.php on line 2023
Database query failed
```

my table:

ptb_friend_requests

```
id | from_user_id | to_user_id | read_request | approved_request | delete_request

1         2              1            0                 0                  0
```

mysql code:

```
function check_new_friends() {
        global $connection;
        global $_SESSION;
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ptb_friend_requests WHERE to_user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND deleted_request='0' AND read_request='0' AND approved_request='0' AND from_user_id != '0'";
        $check_new_friends_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        confirm_query($check_new_friends_set);
        return $check_new_friends_set;      
    }
```

html:

```
$check_profile_views_set = check_profile_views();
while ($newf = mysql_fetch_array($check_profile_views_set)) {

echo "<div class=\"friend-notify\">". $newf['COUNT(id)'] ."</div>";

//$check_new_duos_set = check_new_escort_duos(); while ($newd = mysql_fetch_array($check_new_duos_set)) { ?>

<? echo "". $newf['COUNT(id)'] .""; ?><? } ?>
```

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explainatory – your global variable `$connection` is not an actual MySQL connection, but NULL. So do some debugging to find out way!

Comment: Tip don't trust blindly that the $_SESSION array is safe if you are on an shared webhosting. PHP doesn't check what session id belongs to what site so sessions are prone.. this is an common misbelieve most PHP programmers have..

Answer (score 0):

The global $connection var is not set.

Link to how to connect to a mysql server: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.phpp

For you:

```
global $connection;
$connection=mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
```

And mySQL is not outdated and it's perfectly fine to use it. Just the php API you are using for it is depricated.

Comment: I think that's what he meant -- PHP's ext/mysql is outdated. The MySQL database server is a great choice, one should just use a different PHP extension to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Something is higher up in your program is unsetting or overwriting the global
$connection variable. This is really bad advice but to get your script working 
again you can try removing the $connection parameter from your mysql_query() call 
so that it reads

```
$check_new_friends_set = mysql_query($query);
```

This will make mysql_query() use a previously established connection, if there is one  available